# Microsoft Kinect Skeleton Tracker Linux

Tags: linux, kinect, openni, nite

After shutting down the openni and primesense I couldn't find any skeleton tracker library which works in Linux. Is there anything like NiTE2 available right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at opensource [Skeltrack](https://github.com/joaquimrocha/Skeltrack) library. In case you need the NITE binaries they are available via [Mira project](http://www.mira-project.org/downloads/3rdparty/bin-linux/). OpenNi is now maintained by guys at Occipital(called OpenNi2). Source is available [here](https://github.com/occipital/openni2) and binaries are available [here](http://structure.io/openni).

Comment: There's also nuitrack, which offers paid licenses per sensor, visit their site (https://nuitrack.com/).